# Using Robot Framework for automating IVR tests

Tags: python, robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework and I have only used it to run a few test cases for SMS. 
I am wondering if there is a way to test IVR using Robot Framework.
For example : Use Robot Framework to send out a VOICE CALL Rti's and having it press 1, 2 and stuff like that.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If there are python libraries to do that, it's easy to create keywords in robot. Do you know if there are python libraries for IVR?

Comment: I don't think there are.

Comment: Are you looking to isolate the server itself and mimic a connected client, or are you considering automating the client application?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is possible and you have mainly two options:

The first option is to use AppiumLibrary or AndroidLibrary (Calabash) to do phone calls with Robot Framework in an android phone. It's not an easy option. You would need to discover the locators of the phone application, or the coordinates.

https://github.com/serhatbolsu/robotframework-appiumlibrary

The second option, I believe its more accessible, would be to use a Windows VOIP client and control it using for example the AutoITLibrary.

https://code.google.com/archive/p/robotframework-autoitlibrary/

In fact there is also a 3rd crazy option: you could hack an old phone, and create a Robot Framework custom library in Python that would control the phone with a Raspberry PI and GPIO, connecting the keys switches to the GPIO pins.

That would be a nice hacking project =:)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [PJSIP](https://www.pjsip.org/) and it's python wrapper.

You should start from the [tutorial in python](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Python_SIP/Hello_World) to create a simple library for robotframework.